# Horizontal tangent line of a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric, curves

Suppose $x=t^2,y=t^3$ is a parametric curve. Here's a quote from my textbook:

> The origin, which corresponds to $t=0$, is a **singular** point of the parametric curve, because $dx/dt=2t,dy/dt=3t^2$ are both zero when $t=0$.

So far so good.

But then they write:

> However, the curve has a horizontal tangent line at the origin, because for all $t\neq 0$:
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\frac{3}{2}t$$
>   And thus:
>   $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{t\to 0^-} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

It looked a little odd for me. Nevertheless, I decided to use the same argument to show that the parametric curve $x=2\cos t - \cos (2t), y=2\sin t - \sin(2t)$ has a horizontal tangent line at $t=0$, that is at $(1,0)$.

However my professor said that this is wrong ("because the derivative is not zero" - indeed, $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{t=0}$ is undefined - "$0/0$").

So who is right? Is the existence of the limit a sufficient condition for the (horizontal) tangent line to exist, as my textbook says, or not? I'm confused.

Thanks.

**Short version of the question**: can a parametric curve have a horizontal tangent line at a singular point?

I.e. is $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$ a sufficient condition for a horizontal line to exist (at $t=0$)? (even if the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big |_{t=0}$ itself doesn't exist).

Comment: Reading your comments to the answers below, I think you are unduly concerned about the distinction between $f(x_0)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$. Where we have an isolated point $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)$ does not exist, but $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ does exist, it is common for people to assume without comment that we define $f(x_0)$ as the limit.

Comment: what is your textbook ?

Comment: @KonKan - Calculus by Anton (5th ed.)

Comment: @almagest - unduly? This might be an obvious assumption for some, but not for me. The very fact that my professor dismissed it says that this is not trivial, and at least deserves a mention.

Comment: @user239753: i'm a bit confused: I'm searching in your book (it happens to have a copy of the 10th edition, available right in front of me) but i cannot find the quote you are mentioning. I am actually looking at Ch.10, par.10.1, p.692-705. The example you are mentioning is example 6, p.697. However, the authors simply mention that $t=0$ is a singular point. I cannot find the limit computation you are mentioning. Can you indicate the exact page ?

Comment: @KonKan - are you sure that you have the 5th edition?

Comment: ah, i just noted that it is the 10th ed. do you have a link for the 5th ed?

Comment: @KonKan - unfortunately no. I only have the paperback. Nevertheless, I quoted everything exactly like in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that both your curves are algebraic curves, of equations $x^3 - y^2 = 0$ and $(x^2+y^2-1)^2-4((x-1)^2+y^2)=0$ respectively.

We say that the line $ax + by + c = 0$ is tangent at the point $(x_0, y_0)$ to the curve given by $F(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a **multiple** root of the system $\begin{cases} F(x,y) = 0 \\ ax + by + c = 0 \end{cases}$ (this is the definition that was originally used by algebraic geometers).

In your case, the points are $(0,0)$ in the first case and $(1, 0)$ in the second, and the line to be checked is $y=0$.

Plugging $y = 0$ into $x^3 - y^2 = 0$ gives $x^3 = 0$, which indeed has $x=0$ as a triple root, therefore $y=0$ is tangent to $x^3 - y^2 = 0$ at $(0,0)$.

Plugging $y = 0$ into $(x^2+y^2-1)^2-4((x-1)^2+y^2)=0$ gives $(x^2-1)^2 - 4(x-1)^2 = 0$, or equivalently $(x-1)^2 ((x+1)^2 - 4) = 0$, or again $(x-1)^3 (x+3) = 0$, which indeed has $x=1$ as a triple root (the root $-3$ being simple, meaning that at the point $(-3, 0)$ the line $y=0$ intersects the curve as a *secant*), therefore $y=0$ is tangent to $(x^2+y^2-1)^2-4((x-1)^2+y^2)=0$ at $(1,0)$.

---

Since the bounty giver is still unsure, let us follow [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number#Intersection_multiplicities_for_plane_curves) and compute the intersection number in the first case. Wikipedia gives several methods, one of them is to consider the ideal generated by $y^2 - x^3$ and by $y$ in $\Bbb R[[x,y]]$ (the ring of formal series in $x$ and $y$) and compute the dimension of the quotient vector space $\Bbb R [[x,y]] / (x^3-y^2, y)$.

In the quotient space, both $y$ and $x^3 - y^2$ will become $0$, which implies that $x^3$ also becomes $0$. Therefore, the only powers of $x$ and $y$ that survive in the quotient set are $x^0 = y^0 = 1$, and $x$ and $x^2$ - a total of $3$ linearly independent powers, so $3$ will be the intersection number of $y=0$ and $x^3-y^2$ at $(0,0)$. Since everything $\ge 2$ means tangency, this shows that the line $y=0$ is tangent to $x^3-y^2$ at $(0,0)$.

The same thing could be done with what Wikipedia denotes by $I_{(0,0)}$, letting $P = y$ and $Q = x^3 - y^2$. Applying the properties that you see on that page (the numbers above equal signs are the Wikipedia properties that I apply),

$$I_{(0,0)} (y, x^3-y^2) \overset 6 = I_{(0,0)} (y, x^3) \overset 5 = I_{(0,0)}(x,y) + I_{(0,0)}(x,y) + I_{(0,0)}(x,y) \overset 4 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 .$$

---

The same computations could be done for the second example, it is just that they are more tedious. First, let us translate the curve such that the cusp moves from $(1,0)$ to $(0,0)$ (because, for simplicity, Wikipedia's formulae are given only for $(0,0)$). To do this we shall make the change of variable $x = u + 1$, which will lead to $(u^2 +2u +y^2)^2 -4(u^2+y^2)$. Next,

$$I_{(0,0)} ((u^2 +2u +y^2)^2 -4(u^2+y^2), y) \overset 6 = I_{(0,0)} (u^4 + 4u^3, y) = I_{(0,0)} (u^3 (u+4), y) \overset 5 = I_{(0,0)} (u^3, y) + \\ I_{(0,0)} (u+4, y) = I_{(0,0)} (u, y) + I_{(0,0)} (u, y) + I_{(0,0)} (u, y) + I_{(0,0)} (u+4, y) \overset {3, 4} = 1+1+1+0 = 3 .$$

Again, we obtain an intersection number $\ge 2$, which means tangency.

---

What others have correctly stated is that the two plane curves given in the problem are *not* differentiable submanifolds of $\Bbb R^2$ at the singular points under discussion, therefore they do not fit into the framework of diferential geometry, therefore we may not speak of their tangent spaces at the singular points *as defined in differential geometry* (a proof that an almost identical curve cannot be a smooth submanifold can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231892/showing-something-isnt-a-manifold)). Counterintuitively, though, they do have tangent lines! There is no contradiction, the thing is that we use *two* meanings for "being tangent" that are not synonymous: one comes from differential geometry ("tangent space"), and it doesn't apply here, the other from algebraic geometry ("intersection number"), and it does apply here. In the latter framework, we may speak about "a given line being tangent (or not) to a curve in a point" without speaking of "the tangent space at that curve in that point".

**$y=0$ is tangent to those curves at the specified points. Those curves do not have nicely defined tangent spaces at those points.**

Comment: @user239753: Try these two: ["Elementary Differential Geometry"](https://books.google.com/books?id=9nT1fOwATf0C&printsec=frontcover) by A.N. Pressley, and ["Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces"](https://books.google.ro/books?id=v4vqjgEACAAJ) by M.P. do Carmo. One last word: differential geometry *in general* is interested only in those spaces that are endowed with *regular* parametrizations (because one wants them to be invertible, with their inverses called "local charts"). Most theorems about parametrized curves *assume* the parametrization to be regular.

Comment: @AlexM. Because this is all about subtile nuances: You wrote, the cardiod would be a manifold, because the defining function $F$ is smooth. Aren't you applying the regular value theorem (which is a close relative to the implicite function theorem) here, which means 0 needs to be a regular value for $F$? (Anyway: great answer!)

Comment: @AlexM. - thank you for your refined answer. A bit stupid question - what does "multiple root" mean? It has something to do with algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: @user239753: Yes, exactly. We say that $a$ is a root of order $k$ of $P$ (where $P$ is a polynomial) if and only if $(x-a)^k \mid P$ and $(x-a)^{k+1} \nmid P$. The analogue for algebraic curves is the concept of ["intersection multiplicity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number#Intersection_multiplicities_for_plane_curves).

Comment: @AlexM. - also, do you have a reference for the definition of the tangent (definition that was originally used by algebraic geometers)?

Comment: @user239753: I remember having seen it once in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry" (first edition), but I cannot pin-point the exact place - probably there where the concept of tangent space is introduced, but I wouldn't bet on my memories.

Comment: @AlexM. According to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496815/why-does-the-derivative-not-exist-at-a-cusp) answer by AstroSharp, the curve $y^2=x^3$ has no tangent line (space) at the cusp.

Comment: @ikj: People write many things on the internet, you shouldn't rush to believe them without a critical examination. I have explained AstroSharp's statement in my latest (and hopefully last!) edit. Also, I'm not planning to answer any comments, anymore, I think I've put more than enough work and time into this for a paltry 50 reputation points (not to mention that some ignorant also downvoted my hard-worked answer). Also, not to be mean, but all the other answers currently on this page have severely missed the point (and the subtlety) of the question.

Comment: @AlexM. - thank you, great answer. I don't know why some people downvote both the question and the answers here. I hope that you would find some time to say a few words about other answers here and explain why they are wrong. I think that would be interesting for anybody reading this (especially for Christian Blatter and KonKan). But anyway, I appreciate your patience and hard work.

Comment: @AlexM: I have to confess .. I am the ignorant who downvoted your hard work ;) but give me a moment to explain. your answer (especially after your edit)  seems valid in my eyes and you've obviously put hard work in it ! I give you credit for that. However, I feel it falls outside the spirit and the OP's question: it is a delicate question on a subtle point of parametric differentiation (from the calculus viewpoint) while you certainly view the situation from the algebraic/differential geometric eye.   This is also why i rolled back your retagging.

Comment: However, since the OP has accepted your answer, it might be reasonable to roll back my retagging. P.S.: I've also made a trivial edit to your answer in order to cancel my downvoting but i'm still not upvoting your post ;)  although i find it a valuable piece of work!

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the tangent at some special point you should not try to compute the limit of $y'$ but the actual limit of secant directions at that point. Therefore in your first example you get
$$m_+:=\lim_{t\to0+}{y(t)-y(0)\over x(t)-x(0)}=\lim_{t\to0+}{t^3\over t^2}=0\ ,$$
and similarly $m_-=0$. In your second example you have
$${y(t)-y(0)\over x(t)-x(0)}={2\sin t-\sin(2t)-0\over 2\cos t-\cos(2t)-1}={2\sin t(1-\cos t)\over2\cos t(1-\cos t)}=\tan t\qquad(t\ne0)\ ,$$
and therefore
$$m_+=m_-=\lim_{t\to0}{y(t)-y(0)\over x(t)-x(0)}=0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

the formula $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$$ is valid for computing the derivative at points where $\frac{dx}{dt}\neq 0$. At **singular** points, i.e. points at which $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$ the above formula is not valid. However, this does not imply that the derivative does not exist; only that it is not computable by the above formula.

In such cases, a straightforward application of the definition of derivative (as already done by user Christian Blatter in his answer) can provide the answer:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{(0,0)}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{y(t)-y(0)}{x(t)-x(0)}=\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{y(t)-y(0)}{x(t)-x(0)}=\lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{t^3}{t^2}=0
$$
which shows that the derivative exists at $(0,0)$ and so does the tangent line at $(0,0)$, which is no other than the horizontal axis itself.

**P.S.1:** Note that, when confined to each branch seperately:
$$
y(x_0)=y(x(0))=y(0)=0, \  \ x_0=x(0)=0 \\ y(x)=y(x(t))=y(t)=t^3, \ \ x=x(t)=t^2
$$ 
So, on each one of the functions $y(x)=x^{3/2}$, $y(x)=−x^{3/2}$ i.e. on each one of the branches of the graph below, the following rates of change are identified:
$$\frac{y\big(x(t)\big)−y(x_0)}{x(t)−x_0}=\frac{y(t)−y(0)}{x(t)−x(0)}$$
On the other hand, since $x=t^2\neq 0$ when $t\neq 0$ it should be clear that
$$t\to 0\Leftrightarrow x\to 0$$
At this point, it remains to invoke a classical proposition on the limit of a composite function, claiming that:

> Let the real functions $f,g$, for which $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=g_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $lim_{g\rightarrow g_0}f(g)=l\in \mathbb{R}$.
>   If, furthermore $g(x)\neq g_0$ "close to  $x_0$" (i.e. in some interval $(a,x_0))$, then 
>   $$
> \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f\big(g(x)\big)=\lim_{g\rightarrow g_0}f(g)=l
> $$

Seting $f(x):=\frac{y(x)−y(0)}{x−0}$ and $g(x):=x(t)$ and applying the proposition we get that:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{y(t)−y(0)}{x(t)−x(0)}\equiv \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{y\big(x(t)\big)−y(0)}{x(t)−x(0)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{y(x)−y(0)}{x−0}=\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_0$$
(where the far left term is computed using side limits: for the upper branch  $t>0$ thus $t\to0\Leftrightarrow t\to0^+$ while for the lower branch $t<0$ thus $t\to0\Leftrightarrow t\to0^-$).

**P.S.2:** Regarding your final question: I do not believe that the existence of the limit is a sufficient condition, because generally, a differentiable function at $x_0$ need not have a continuous derivative at $x_0$: In other words, there may well be a situation at which: $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)\neq f'(x_0)$.

However, this is not the case for the **semicubical parabola**, as we can see from its graph 
[image]

which is probably what the author of your textbook had in his mind. He computes the limit of the derivative just as if we can imagine the tangent "slipping" accross either of the branches to "continuously" become horizontal. In my opinion, he implicitly uses the assumption that the derivative of the semicubical parabola is a continuous function; and he probably does that, based on the shape of the graph.

Comment: Intuitively I understand. But in the definition of the derivative we use $\frac{y(x)-y(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ and not $\frac{y(t)-y(0)}{x(t)-x(0)}$. That is, we must find $y(x)$ first. Otherwise, can you prove rigorously that it works with $t$?

Comment: Please read carefully: There is nothing intuitive here. (Only the idea described in your textbook seems intuitive). When confined to each branch seperately:  $$y(x_0)=y(x(0))=y(0), \ \  y(x)=y(x(t))=y(t) \\ x_0=x(0), \ \ x=x(t)$$ So, on each one of the functions $y=x^{3/2}$, $y=-x^{3/2}$ i.e. on each of the branches of the above graph, the rates of change you are writing are identified: $$\frac{y(x)-y(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\frac{y(t)-y(0)}{x(t)-x(0)}$$ On the other hand, since $x=t^2$ it should be clear that $$t\to0\Leftrightarrow x\to0$$

Comment: i've added the above comment to the post

Comment: It should be $y(x(t))=(t^2)^3=t^6$, no? (I know that in this case it doesn't change the limit, but still). Thank you. 
P.S. - Also, I don't understand why somebody downvotes the answers here.

Comment: actually, for $t>0$: $$y(x(t))=\pm (x(t))^{3/2}=\pm (t^2)^{3/2}=\pm t^3$$ So, for $t\in (-\infty, +\infty)$:  $$y(t)=t^3$$

Comment: why the downvoting ? if there is some mathematical objection, please explain. I'd be glad to know.

Comment: this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496815/195021 is relevant (not implying that i adopt the answers at that post).

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to two different things here..

For the semi-cubical parabola curve $y=x^{3/2}$ there is horizontal tangent at the cusp y=0 or t=0.

For cardoid, depending on the cusp contact point chosen, slope of cusp tangent varies, look at all cusps of  [epicycloids](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=epicycloid&rlz=1RMBKJA_enUS574US574&oq=epicycloid&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-GB&espvd=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=K7odV-DCMMG3mwXO4IagCw#gws_rd=cr&imgrc=tqogZqTB_-LM7M%3A):

EDIT 1:

Since it is passing through infinite curvature which is rate of change of tangent inclination, the slope is ***changing very fast and undefined.***

It can be also seen at the point $(1,0)$ Changing the multiple angle

$$ x=2\cos t - \cos (n t), y=2\sin t - \sin( n t) $$

has the effect of influencing curvature. It changes from (positive for circle) to negative for looped case, via the present central cardoid case of infinite curvature.

The direction of tangent is vertical, indeterminate and vertical respectively

[image: Cardoids]

Comment: In both cases $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$ yet $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big |_{t=0}$ is undefined. The question is whether in such a situation a horizontal tangent line exists. The textbook says it does, yet my professor claims that for a horizontal tangent line to exist the derivative must EXIST and be equal to zero, that is we must have $\frac{dy}{dx}\Big |_{t=0}=0$.

Comment: please read my comment again. I'm talking about the **value of the derivative** which does **NOT** exist. There is a difference between the **limit** (which indeed can be found with L'Hospital) and the **actual value**.

Comment: Note that you should not stop hunting for the L'Hospital limit if the first order evaluation fails. Do not conclude that it is undefined. At the cusp we are dealing with second orders and so limit of $ f''(t)/g^{''}(t)$ should be next evaluated.

Comment: unfortunately, you do not understand me. Here $dy/dx \neq 0$ even though $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$. Do you know there is a difference between limit and value of the function? Take $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 \text{ if } x\neq0\\
1 \text{ if } x=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$. Here $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$$ yet $f(0)\neq 0$. The same goes here. $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$ yet $\frac{dy}{dx} \Big |_{t=0}\neq 0$  ! Do you understand?

Comment: Ok, we resume after sometime,else moderator may indicate chat room.